EAN 13 with leading 0 is being interpreted with UPCA
My app can scan both EAN-13 and UPC-A barcodes. When I have a valid EAN13 barcode with a leading 0, the 0 is being removed by dependence , and it becomes a valid UPC-A code.
Attached is an example of barcodes that are valid for this scenario. 
My application is developed with Ionic and Capacitor, using the Capacitor Barcode Scanner community plugin for reading barcodes (https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-barcode-scanner). One possible solution would be to create a function that adds the digit "0" to the beginning and checks if the result is a valid EAN-13. However, in cases where UPC-A is also valid for the EAN-13 format, always adding this zero can lead to inconsistencies. How can I resolve this issue more effectively?

EAN-13 with a leading zero is UPC-A (by definition, part of the EAN-13 spec). They will generate the same barcode symbol, as your images demonstrate.  There is no way for a scanner to tell the difference.
Every UPC-A value can have a leading zero added to it to encode as EAN-13.  So not sure what you are asking or trying to differentate.

Hi @MarkWarren! The problem is that my application performs the search based on the code read. The removal of the leading zero occurs internally due to the dependency I use to read barcodes. As the app searches for items with the read value, when the return does not include zero, it cannot find the corresponding items.

You'll just have to query twice then when the scanner returns a 12-digit UPC-A.  First for the UPC-A, then for the zero-added EAN-13.  There is no change in check digit so a simple prefix-zero is all that is needed.

@GabrielGameleiradosSantos Additional detail has been provided in this answer to your original question:
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-barcode-scanner/issues/31#issuecomment-2433991350

Hi @MarkWarren.  Do you think it would be a good idea to show the operator, when scanning the barcode, two options in a modal: one with the '0' at the beginning and one without, so he can choose? I would explain that the code read is a subset of the UPC-A.

@MarkWarren I was able to analyze that in the BarcodeScanner class that implements the reading and persistence of the read barcode, the barcodeResult function is responsible for inserting the read content, this function uses getText to search for the content, which belongs to the BarcodeResult class. BarcodeResult is imported from com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeResult, which in turn uses the Result class, imported from com.google.zxing.Result. So I also wouldn't be able to change the dependency because there are other layers.
